# Outlook Forms on Outlook for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2011

I get a weekly email from my company containing an Outlook form that I need to reply to. However, I have a Mac and cannot get the form to show on Outlook. Anyone know of a way to use Outlook's form feature on a Mac? It is Outlook 2011 FYI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, according to Microsoft...

http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/admin/item/a2a4d247-f9f3-4b35-b298-ceb147669dd7

If you scroll down, at the top of Mail Features:

- Enables **Outlook forms**, voting buttons, and receipt tracking

  - Implemented in Outlook for Mac 2011? **No**
  - Implemented in Outlook 2010 for Windows? **Yes**

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that on their site. Bummer :(